# Is this std::vector and std::shared_ptr memory leakage a bug?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, shared-ptr, allocation

Assume this class `Foo`:

```
struct Foo {
    std::shared_ptr<int> data;
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Foo>> foos;
};
```

- it has a pointer to an int
- it has a pointer to all instances that will exist in this program (therefore one of these instances == `*this`)

Let's create a instance of `Foo` and take a look at the `use_count()` of its `.data` member variable after having added some instances to `.foos`:

```
int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.data = std::make_shared<int>(5);
    foo.foos = std::make_shared<std::vector<Foo>>();
    foo.foos->resize(8);

    for (auto & f : *foo.foos) {
        f.data = foo.data;
        f.foos = foo.foos;
    }
    std::cout << "use count: " << foo.data.use_count() << '\n';    
}
```

output:

```
use count: 9
```

Which is fine (1 `foo` + 8 `.foos`).
However, it seem that when `main()` returns, there will still be  <strike>9</strike> 8 pointers pointing to `.data`! This can be demonstrated by putting `foo` into a local scope and letting one additional pointer point to `.data` to observe this pointers `use_count()` afterwards:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
    std::cout << "use count | before: " << ptr.use_count() << '\n';

    { //begin scope
        Foo foo;
        foo.data = std::make_shared<int>(5);
        foo.foos = std::make_shared<std::vector<Foo>>();
        foo.foos->resize(8);

        for (auto & f : *foo.foos) {
            f.data = foo.data;
            f.foos = foo.foos;
        }
        ptr = foo.data;
        std::cout << "use count | inside: " << ptr.use_count() << '\n';

    } //end scope

    std::cout << "use count | after: " << ptr.use_count() << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
use count | before: 0
use count | inside: 10
use count | after: 9
```

Which is not good. I would excpect `use count | after` to be `1` since `foo` and all its members should get deconstructed at the end of the scope. Well, `foo` definetely got deconstructed (otherwise `use_count | after` would be `10` and not `9`) but its `.foos` vector pointer weren't deconstructed. And `ptr` is just a `std::shared_ptr<int>` and therefore has nothing to do with `struct Foo` at all. All this can be fixed by providing `struct Foo` a destructor which `reset()`s the `.foos->data` pointer manually:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    ~Foo() {
        for (auto& p : *foos) {
            p.data.reset();
        }
    }

    std::shared_ptr<int> data;
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Foo>> foos;
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
    std::cout << "use count | before: " << ptr.use_count() << '\n';

    {
        Foo foo;
        foo.data = std::make_shared<int>(5);
        foo.foos = std::make_shared<std::vector<Foo>>();
        foo.foos->resize(8);

        for (auto & f : *foo.foos) {
            f.data = foo.data;
            f.foos = foo.foos;
        }
        ptr = foo.data;
        std::cout << "use count | inside: " << ptr.use_count() << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "use count | after: " << ptr.use_count() << '\n';
}
```

producing the nicer output:

```
use count | before: 0
use count | inside: 10
use count | after: 1
```

But it seem weird that one has to manually reset these pointers. Why do `std::vector` or `std::shared_ptr` not do that automatically here? Is it a bug?

---

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.9.5 - Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do not get it, at the ent ptr still points to foos data and use count is 1? So...what is the problem?

Comment: I see...sorry..

Comment: The pointer will be released when the program goes out of main() scope.

Comment: @tunglt but does it do that at any scope? I had the case where I stored a SoundBuffer in a similiar scenario and always got the warning "AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed" when the program closes. It moved through several layers of scopes without getting cleared.

Comment: there is no bug, this is the expected behavior. You have to manually reset those nested `Foo`s because you're creating circular reference (`Foo`s in the vector have a shared_ptr to the vector its in, thereby keeping themselves alive) and shared_ptr is not designed to handle it.

Comment: Offtopic: deconstructed == destroyed...

Comment: @StackDanny this reference cycle was already recognized when designing smart pointers, and this is one of the most common use of weak_ptr.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Foo>>` this is most definitely not what you want. You need a vector of *pointers*.

Comment: @n.m., the `vector` has to be a pointer. in my real code I have a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>>` scenario, but for the sake of simplicity I removed one layer of confusion.

Comment: @n.m., no, I know. I mean that `std::vector` has to be inside `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @n.m. here is the same [code](https://pastebin.com/kqjGGnj2) but with `std::shared<std::Vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>>` - still displays the use_count of 9.

Comment: You have introduced more confusion than you tried to eliminate by this.

Comment: @n.m. but it's the same program? you said I should use a vector of pointers, but it doesn't make a difference here so I don't see the reason why I should include in the code.

Comment: The class as originally shown simply doesn't make a lot of sense. I have no idea what you mean to accomplish here. Technical problems that you observe may or may not arise because of flaws of the overall design, so it's important to get the design fixed first.

Comment: @UmNyobe "_this is one of the most common use of weak_ptr_" No. The most common use is for a cache system and supporting making a `shared_ptr` from the an object (as with intrusive ptr)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is that you have a circular reference.

When `foo` is destroyed, it decreases **reference count** of its `shared_ptr`, but those don't reach zero.

So even if `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Foo>>` is "inaccessible" , there are still pointer on it. (Note: Garbage collector uses "accessibility" to collect/free the pointers).

Usual method to break the cycle is to use `std::weak_ptr`.

Comment: Maybe to further clarify: every entry of `foo.foos` is a `Foo` that keeps a reference to both `foo.data` and `foo.foos`. At that point all pointers to `foo.foos` are interchangeable and deleting one does not affect the rest.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I was searching for. I accept the answer though I yet don't know how to use `weak_ptr` in this example code. it doesn't seem to have a `->` operator of sorts.

Comment: You have to [lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock) it before using the associated `std::shared_ptr` (check for `nullptr`).

Comment: Ok I understand it. But since `weak_ptr` wants to be set to an existing `shared_ptr` I will have to put both a `shared_ptr<vector<Foo>>` *and* a `weak_ptr<vector<Foo>>` inside the struct, right?

Comment: You don't have to put both. Hard to say the right way to do as your sample is simplified. `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Foo>>` seems to be an option.

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried but I couldn't utilise `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Foo>>` in this example. like how do I setup the vector? `for (auto &f : foo.foos) { f.lock()->foos = foo.foos; }` doesn't work..

Comment: use weak reference only when you don't have an ownership or a dependency relation; in general weak something is not a fix for a deep design problem

Answer (score 1):

You created a circular dependency: Each `Foo` contains `shared_ptr`s (i.e. shares ownership) of all other `Foo`s. This means no `Foo` will ever get destructed: To be destroyed, the `use_count` would have to be zero. But it cannot be zero before entering the destructor because every other `Foo` still holds a reference.

This is a classic case of the limits of shared ownership - contrary to some beliefs, it does not automagically solve all your ownership problems.

I would also question the point of each `Foo` storing the same pointer to all `Foo`s. If that's what you want to do, it should just be `static`, but that doesn't sound like good design either. Maybe you could detail the actual problem you want so solve (in a new question)?

Comment: Ownership by definition is not circular. If you end up with circular ownership, you have a semantic error.